# What determines whether Cortana opens full-screen or in a little box in the corner?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1703, cortana

Since the Creators Update, Cortana seems to open full-screen pretty often when activated by voice, but it seems kind of random why. What determines whether it opens the full-screen overlay versus in her little box in the bottom-left corner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's based on whether or not you are actively using your computer. If it hasn't received input in the last five seconds, it will open the full-screen overlay. If it has, it will only open the little box in the corner so as not to disturb your work.